# how to show buttonwith softkeyboard when the user focuses the edit text in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing an application in which I have to show a button on the Soft keyboard  when ever user focuses on the edit text which is in **web view** like following.How can I do this .Any help will be appreciable. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Use below property of edit text

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: but edit text is in web view like <input type="text"> .but thanks for your answer